# Java string split function acting strange

Tags: java, string, split

I am noticing strange behaviour when using the `split()` method in Java.

I have a string as follows: `0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10`

```
String currentString[] = br.readLine().split("\\|");
System.out.println("Length:"+currentString.length);
for(int i=0;i < currentString.length;i++){
     System.out.println(currentString[i]);
}
```

This will produce the desired results:

```
Length: 11
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

However if I receive the string: `0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8||`

I get the following results:

```
Length: 8
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

The final 2 empties are omitted.  I need the empties to be kept.  Not sure what i am doing wrong. I have also tried using the split in this manner as well. ...`split("\\|",-1);`

but that returns the entire string with a length of 1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A couple of tips unrelated to your question. I highly recommend you indent your code the way Paulo Santos did, to make it *much* easier to read. Also, your "C style" for() loop can be replaced by `for (String str : currentString) { System.out.println(str); }` which is easier to read and harder to mess up (e.g. by accidentally using `<=` instead of `<`). Finally, it is a bit misleading that `currentString` is not a String, but rather an array of Strings. Consider calling it `currentStringArray` or something.

Comment: I should also mention that if my string has empty values for some delimiters inbetween the first and last index, it catches those whitespaces just fine, it only acts strange if the very last 2 delimeters are empty.  

Example:
0|1|2|3|||6|7|8|9|10
0
1
2
3


6
7
8
9
10

Comment: It works fine for me with a -1. Double check that you're not making a simple mistake, like re-running the code without remembering to recompile it.

Comment: Thank's for the tips MatrixFrog I will make the changes you suggested.  And I wasn't sure how to correctly surround my code with the tags to format it as Paulo Santos did (I did read the faq for it but could not implement the backtick method mentioned and left it as such).

Thank you for the help and guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behavior of split is to not return empty tokens (because of a zero limit). Use the two parameter split method with a limit of -1 will give you all empty tokens in the return.

UPDATE:

Test code as follows:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String currentString[] = "0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8||".split("\\|", -1);
    System.out.println("Length:"+currentString.length); 
    for(int i=0;i < currentString.length;i++){ System.out.println(currentString[i]); }
  }
}
```

Output as follows:

```
Length:11
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
--- BLANK LINE --    
--- BLANK LINE --
```

The "--- BLANK LINE --" is put in by me to show that the return is blank. It is blank once for the empty token after 8| and once for the empty trailing token after the last |.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: I have tried using the -1 as mentioned in my post but that returns the entire string with a length of 1.  As follows:
0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8||

Not sure why?

Comment: Actually, by default only *trailing* empties are removed.

Answer (score 4):

String.split() is weird.

Its extreme weirdness, in this and other ways, are some of the reasons why we made [Splitter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html).

It has less surprising behavior and lots of flexibility.

Comment: I wouldn't call it weird that empty strings between delimiters are removed. The weirdness is that it ONLY does this with empty strings at the end, not in the middle!

Answer (score 1):

My Java is a little bit rusty, but shouldn't it be:

```
String currentString[] = "0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8||".split("\\|");
System.out.println("Length:"+currentString.length); 
for(int i = 0; i < currentString.length; i++)
{
  System.out.println(currentString[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Note the double backslash. This is because the argument of split() is interpreted as a regular expression. You want to match the character `|` which is done with the regular expression `\|` which is represented by the String literal `"\\|"`

Comment: My code has the double slash, i'm not sure why it doesn't translate well in the forum.

Comment: Oh okay. You should be able to edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: @astro - it is because you used <code>...</code> rather than the StackOverflow wiki syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `indexOf()` and then `substring()` for this to work. I don't think you can empty string by using `split()` only.

Comment: hmm not sure what you mean, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, I think this is the default behavior of split, Anyway please try this:

String currentString[] = br.readLine().replace("||","| |").split("\|");
System.out.println("Length:"+currentString.length); 
for(int i=0;i < currentString.length;i++){ 
   System.out.println(currentString[i]); 
}

This has not been tested yet, but i think this should do the trick.

Comment: this took me a step further in that it added to the length by one index but missed the last index.  This is due to the fact that the final index ends as such |(value) not || so the empty space is never added.

Should I be using the stringTokenizer method? I know it's deprecated but I think that would be more effective as i'm not sure why this isn't functioning as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code, I used your solution, it works:

```
public class SplitTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      String text = "0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8||";
      String pattern = "\\|";
      String [] array = text.split(pattern, -1);
          System.out.println("array length:" + array.length);
          for(int i=0; i< array.length; i++) 
          System.out.print(array[i]+ " ");
        } 
 }
```

output is:

```
array length:11
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```